# I get InvocationTargetException and I don't know how to know real error?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, invocationtargetexception

I have a class that have a method that sends an email using javax.mail .I've compiled the code and it was working fine,then suddenly I started to get InvocationTargetException and I don't know what is causing it.

Here is my code :

```
    import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class SendEmailClass {

    private static String USER_NAME = "email@domain.com"  ; 
    private static String PASSWORD = "Password";  
    private static String RECIPIENT = "email@domain.com";

 private SendEmailClass () {

    }




    public static String getStr (String str)   {


        String from = USER_NAME;
        String pass = PASSWORD;
        String[] to = { RECIPIENT }; // list of recipient email addresses
        String subject = "Test Email";
        String body = "mail notification  " + str ;

        SendEmail(from, pass, to, subject, body);



return "test" + str ;

    }



 public static void SendEmail(String from, String pass, String[] to, String subject, String body)  {


        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        String host = "Some IP Address";
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);




        try {
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];

            // To get the array of addresses
            for( int i = 0; i < to.length; i++ ) {
                toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
            }

            for( int i = 0; i < toAddress.length; i++) {
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
            }

            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(body);
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(host, from, pass);
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();


        }

        catch (AddressException ae) {
            ae.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (MessagingException me) {
            me.printStackTrace();
        }



    }






}
```

When I invoke method "getStr" I get that exception ,I tried to handle it by putting catch block after at the end of "SendEmail" method , so the method becomes like this :

```
public static void SendEmail(String from, String pass, String[] to, String subject, String body)  {


        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        String host = "40.101.62.34";
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);




        try {
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];

            // To get the array of addresses
            for( int i = 0; i < to.length; i++ ) {
                toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
            }

            for( int i = 0; i < toAddress.length; i++) {
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
            }

            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(body);
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(host, from, pass);
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();


        }

        catch (AddressException ae) {
            ae.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (MessagingException me) {
            me.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (InvocationTargetException ex){
            // handle exception
        }

    }






}
```

But then I get that : "Unreachable catch block for InvocationTargetException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body"

How do I handles this and find what causing the exception?
Please help .

Comment: it means you should remove this: catch (InvocationTargetException ex){
            // handle exception
        } because this can never be the situation

Comment: Yes,but when I remove it,then I get InvocationTargetException. I want to know what is the real error is.How it says it cant be thrown?! I am confused.

Comment: could you show more of your stacktrace? also, it is possible that AddressException and/or MessageException are childclasses of InvocationTargetException, which may lead to this.

Comment: It could also be that you are using two different type of InvocationTargetException (different packages)

Comment: Show stacktrace, including pointers to the lines in your code.

Comment: I only get the words  "InvocationTargetException"

Comment: ... you should get more. at least, if that Exception is thrown.

Comment: Well I don't know what happened,but I just moved the code to another test environment and in different server and and compiled it and it works ! Maybe its something related to Java version.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is telling you that you have code that tries to handle an InvocationTargetException which it can *tell* will never be thrown so it is superfluous, and can be safely deleted without changing the behavior of your program.

Delete this catch block and try again.

Comment: you may want to read the comments. That was my first guess as well, but he replies to it, that when he deletes it, an InvocationTargetException is thrown.